# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken with devise, rails and docker

Tags: docker, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, authenticity-token

I'm getting InvalidAuthenticityToken exception on every post request for my rails 5 app, running in docker container. I'm using devise in application, is this something related to devise or anything else?

Comment: Are you making this post request from a rails view? or using other tools like Postman, curl, etc.?

Could you please share the request from your logs?

Comment: @TarekN.Elsamni making request from rails view.

Comment: I think you are missing the `authenticity_token` in your form in the view.

Are you building your form in native/pure html or using rails helpers?

Comment: @TarekN.Elsamni authenticity_token is present there in form and getting submitted to server.As i think, it is something related to docker and devise.